# read value from file then pass value in sql UPDATE command(python script)

Tags: python, mysql, mariadb

So hopefully an easy question although I'm having trouble putting it together using google.  I have a windows application that writes values to a text file which I need to pull from text and send to mysql.  I can manually do everything I need but having trouble pulling the value from the text file and sending it to sql in an update statement(won't accept variables).  Please let me know if there is a way to use variables in my UPDATE statement.

the data variable is what I'm trying to pass.

Code below:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import MySQLdb

file = open('tvalue.txt', 'r')
data = file.read()

# Open database connection
db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost","testuser","test123","TESTDB" )
# prepare a cursor object using cursor() method
cursor = db.cursor()

cursor.execute("UPDATE table1 SET waiting=data where dept='billing'" )


    # Commit your changes in the database
db.commit()

# disconnect from server
db.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
c.execute("UPDATE table1 SET waiting=%s where dept='billing'", (data.strip(),))
```

Should do the trick.

Take a look to the first example at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-example-cursor-select.html

And remember not to use concatenation to avoid SQL Injection.

If you don't want *waiting* to contain any new line or spaces at the beginning or end use strip.

**EDIT:** the query has to be a tuple, in this case, consisting in a single value, a **,** is needed.